# MS Access SQL code - query issue with NOT IN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to find out which partners has not paid the monthly tuition in a particular month.

I have a table called `Socios` containing all partners names `SocioNome` and another table called `RegistroPagamento` contaning all payments done (This particular table is fulfilled by a form where the user input the Partner Name, Amount Paid and which particular month/year the payment is related to).

I have created a query where I used the SQL code below:

```
SELECT [SocioNome]
FROM [Socios] NOT IN
(SELECT [SocioNome] FROM [RegistroPagamento] WHERE [MesBoleto] = [Forms]![Selecionar_MCobranca]![TBoxMes] AND [AnoBoleto] = [Forms]![Selecionar_MCobranca]![TBoxAno]);
```

`[Selecionar_MCobranca]` is the form I have mentioned before and the `[TBoxMes]` & `[TBoxAno]` are the combo boxes from the form which the user can select the month and the year the payment refers to.

When I run the code, a error message pops up indicating that there is a FORM clause syntax issue, and I don't know exactly what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT IN` is a comparison operator in the `WHERE` clause.  It does not belong in the `FROM` cluase.  I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead.  The idea is:

```
SELECT s.SocioNome
FROM Socios as s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM RegistroPagamento as rp
                  WHERE rp.MesBoleto = [Forms]![Selecionar_MCobranca]![TBoxMes] AND
                        rp.AnoBoleto = [Forms]![Selecionar_MCobranca]![TBoxAno] AND
                        rp.SocioNome = s.SocioNome
                 );
```

`NOT IN` returns *no* rows if *any* row in the subquery is `NULL`.  To protect against this, just use `NOT EXISTS`.  It has the expected behavior in this case.